# Ajax fresh input field generated by PHP DOM

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am a student studying Ajax to change the value of an input field generated with PHP DOM.
Here is the code that generates the table rows.

```
<?php
                    $totalval = 0;
                    foreach($_SESSION as $name=>$value){
                        $total = 0;

                        if(substr($name,0,5) == "item_"){
                            $id = substr($name,5,4);
                            $cart_xml= new DomDocument;
                            $cart_xml->Load('prod_db.xml');

                            $root=$cart_xml->getElementsByTagName('root')->item(0);
                            $product=$root->getElementsByTagName('product');

                            foreach($product as $prod){
                                $itms_id=$prod->getElementsByTagName('prod_id')->item(0)->nodeValue;
                                $itms_categ=$prod->getElementsByTagName('prod_categ')->item(0)->nodeValue;
                                $itms_imgsrc=$prod->getElementsByTagName('prod_imgsrc')->item(0)->nodeValue;
                                $itms_name=$prod->getElementsByTagName('prod_name')->item(0)->nodeValue;
                                $itms_price=$prod->getElementsByTagName('prod_price')->item(0)->nodeValue;
                                $itms_stock=$prod->getElementsByTagName('prod_stock')->item(0)->nodeValue;

                                if($id==$itms_id){
                                    $price = floatval($itms_price);
                                    $total=$price*$value;
                                    ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><img src="<?php echo $itms_imgsrc?>" class="citemimg"/></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <p class="prodname"><?php echo ucfirst($itms_name);?></p>
                                            <p class="prodcateg"><?php echo ucfirst($itms_categ)?></p>
                                            <p class="prodprice"><?php echo "Php. ".number_format($itms_price,2)?></p>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="cartAmount;">

                                            <img onclick="ajaxMinus('<?php echo $itms_id;?>','<?php echo $itms_stock;?>')" class="carticons" src="images/logos/Minus_r_50px.png"/>

                                            <input type="number" min="1" max="<?php echo $itms_stock;?>" class="cartqty" id="itmQty<?php echo $itms_id;?>" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" disabled>

                                            <img onclick="ajaxAdd('<?php echo $itms_id;?>','<?php echo $itms_stock;?>')" class="carticons" src="images/logos/Add_r_50px.png"/>
                                        </td>
                                        <td><?php echo "Php. ".number_format($total,2);?></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <a href="cart_actionCart.php?del=<?php echo $itms_id;?>&maxval=<?php echo $itms_stock;?>">
                                                <img class="carticons" src="images/logos/Remove_r_50px.png"/>
                                            </a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <?php
                                }
                            }
                            $totalval+=$total;
                        }
                    }
                ?>
```

And I make my image tag clickable by adding

```
`onclick="ajaxMinus('<?php echo $itms_id;?>','<?php echo $itms_stock;?>')"`
```

And I add as well

```
`onclick="ajaxAdd('<?php echo $itms_id;?>','<?php echo $itms_stock;?>')"`
```

And here is my simple function for ajaxAdd

```
function ajaxAdd(id,maxqty){
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
            xhrAdd=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else{
            if(window.ActiveXObject){
                try{
                    xhrAdd=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                catch(e){}
            }
        }
        if(xhrAdd){
            xhrAdd.onreadystatechange=minusQty;
            xhrAdd.open("GET","cart_actionCart.php?add="+id+"&maxval="+maxqty,true);
            xhrAdd.send();
        }
        else{
            alert("Couldn't create an XMLHttpRequest");
        }
    }
    function minusQty(){
        if(xhrAdd.readyState == 4 && xhrMinus.staus == 200){
            document.getElementById('itmQty'+id).value = xhrAdd.responseText;
        }
    }
```

This is working but my problem is the input value is not changing until I refresh the page, where is my problem? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Anything loaded in via AJAX will not have a listener unless the parent element was there in the first place.

As an example, I had a form HTML come through AJAX, and the datepicker would not work, until I changed the original code from this:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker();
```

To this:

```
$("body").on("focusin", ".datepicker", function(){
        $(this).datepicker();
});
```

Because body is there always, the listener now works. This will probably what your issue is too, so I suggest trying to adapt your listeners as above.

Comment: oh o see, can you give me more  example similar? is this a jquery? i tried to add separate jquery functions to  but rather it only change ai once

Comment: put the listener code on the main page and not the ajax loaded page, and you only need to do it once

Comment: sorry but i have a hard time understanding jquery my self.
'$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#qtySubtract").click(function() {
    $('.cartqty').load('  .cartqty');
    });' i add something like this

Comment: how would you add an onclick forinstance in plain javascript? Do that, only make it focusin

Comment: you are using jQuery too?

Comment: hmm. . . after researching about how to make cart some added jquery so i am totally new with it. can you adopt your examples to my code sorry for inconvenience i have a really difficult time with it

Comment: just try making it $('body').on('click', 'id-or-class-here', function(){ // do whatever you need to happen in here});

Comment: hmm. after searching how i can make cart and adopting to my logic of codes. i see some use jquery combined with ajax but i have difficulties trying to understand syntax's.

Comment: it shouldn't be?